# Uninstall grub from Debian (I'am using systemd-boot!)

Tags: debian, grub2, grub, systemd-boot

The first thing I do with a new Linux box is to install systemd-boot. Grub, one would think this abomination was made of the hand of MS! 

Okay, back to subject:
I just ran an upgrade on my new Debian Buster and a new kernel update was available and the update-package seems to look for grub and it made me think I better remove it, not that I expect the upgrade to run much smoother though, but it seems to be the right thing to do, I never thought of that. 
As I said it's disabled in favour of Systemd-boot which works perfectly on the box..
It seems I got these grub related packages installed:
[image]

Should I just uninstall them all? Any perticarly order? Any other steps to do? E.g. is it safe to delete the folder **/boot/grub/**

Or am I better off just leaving it?

Comment: I know I can just run `apt-get remove....` but I was thinking there might be more to it than any other "normal" package, maybe  grub might be more "integrated" into the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem this did the job: `apt-get purge grub-common` (it will include configurations files which `remove` will not).

And to remove unused dependencies (at least in my case):
`apt-get purge libfreetype6 libfuse2 libpng16-16 mokutil shim-helpers-amd64-signed shim-signed-common shim-unsigned`

System booted without problems.
Hope the next upgrade will run without problems.

Answer (score 0):

yes, but kernel package has dependency to grub and grub will get re-installed after being uninstalled

at least on my proxmox server and debian 11 server, "apt-cache depends " will show "recommends: grub..."

see https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/minor-grub-probe-error-during-update.124284/post-541320

Comment: I guess "recommends" is the keyword. That doesn't sounds like its mandatory. And I always install package excl. recommended packages (using apt parameter).
But can't say for sure, haven't updated my debian test-server yet.

Comment: i you do apt-get upgrade , grub will get re-installed, but you can "apt-mark hold" those packages and then they will get ignored